# How to define a base class which must be inherited?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-xe2

I have created a component which its self should never be instantiated, but instead it must be inherited. Similar concept to the `TThread`. What can I do to this component to ensure it's never instantiated by its self without being inherited? For example, when the object is instantiated, raise an exception that the class is required to be inherited, or if possible, don't even let any project compile where an instance of this component base is attempted.

Comment: Do you mean, declare it as abstract?

Comment: @MartynA Actually yes.

Comment: @MartynA PS - You mean Define, not Declare. That is a difference which is often confused, I've just recently started to understand the difference. Declare refers to variables or fields within an object, whereas Define refers to types and constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was mentioned in the comments by TLama, but was never made an answer, so I'll answer this.

```
type
  TEvilClass = class
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TGoodClass = class(TEvilClass)

  end;

{ TEvilClass }

constructor TEvilClass.Create;
begin
  if ClassType = TEvilClass then
    raise Exception.Create('I''m the evil class which cannot be instantiated!');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  EvilClass: TEvilClass;
begin
  EvilClass := TEvilClass.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GoodClass: TGoodClass;
begin
  GoodClass := TGoodClass.Create;
end;
```

This scenario is also one which makes sense to create your own exception type..

```
type
  EvilClassException = Exception;

  TEvilClass = class(TComponent)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  ...

constructor TEvilClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  if ClassType = TEvilClass then
    raise EvilClassException.Create('I''m the evil class which cannot be instantiated!');
end;
```

Comment: Id give @TLama some credits in your answer and add the link he posted.  I kinda liked the TEvilClass/TGoodClass example :)

Answer (score 5):

In XE2, you can declare the class as abstract:

```
type TMyclass = class abstract (TAncestor)
```

Upd: it seems that Delphi still allows creating abstract classes (although documentation for some versions says it doesn't). Compiler should give a warning though.

Probably your class has some virtual method that has to be overridden (and that's why it must be inherited from). If so, just make the method `abstract`, and you will get an exception when it's invoked in the base class.

Comment: Not sure why the term `abstract` never came to mind in the first place, after MartynA's comment, I tried defining `= abstract class()` but no luck, then realized the two needed to be switched around.

Comment: Was this introduced in a certain Delphi version, or how long as it been there?

Comment: Read [`the note`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Classes_and_Objects#Class_Types): *Delphi allows instantiating a class declared abstract, for backward compatibility, but this feature should not be used anymore.*

Comment: In Delphi 2009 I didn't get even warning and there was no problem to make an instance of such `abstract` class. I would personally do it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/RDMD6pMU).

Comment: @TLama Thanks! That's insanity, what's the point of having abstract classes if they can be instantiated? I remember some docs telling that  they cannot.

Comment: I think they must have been designed on a *should not* basis rather than *can not* or *will not*

Comment: @TLama Nice trick, but I'd prefer doing this in `AfterConstruction` (you may want to have several constructors, or to call inherited constructor, especially if it's parameterized).

Comment: This is one heck of a pet peeve of mine (stupid warning telling me that I'm instantiating a class with abstract method; it shouldn't allow it at all!)

Comment: I like this evil class :-) Make that code an answer and I'll change my accepted answer

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I've never seen such a warning. Of course, I may have never defined a class that its self has an abstract method. However usually, classes which have an abstract method are intended to be inherited.

Comment: I expect that you can configure the warning to be an error. Then the compiler can verify. Apart from instances made through meta classes.